# S-PFQP-G80 package

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, reflow

I am having some troubles soldering a  [S-PFQP-G80 package](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/mpqf052b/mpqf052b.pdf) since I get solder bridges between pins after putting it into the reflow oven and I was wondering it would make sense to decrease the pad width in the footprint. I was hoping to get a bit more space between pads and prevent bridging. Currently footprint dimensions are 0.3mmx1.45mm and the pin width is 0.17-0.27mm. This being said I guess that I would have to reassure that the pins and pads are perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The leads should get aligned when the chip is soldered, by surface tension pulling them into place. You should be able to decrease the pad width slightly. If it's only a few that are bridged you could use desolder braid.